# Extracting an entity from a Java List which is in Request Body

Tags: java, json, soapui

I have the following method.

```
@PostMapping(value = Constants.EMPLOYEE_INSERT,produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String employeeInsert(@RequestHeader(ConstantsValue.ID) @NotBlank final String id,
        @RequestBody final List<EmployeeData> empData) {
    
    
    if (empData != null) {
        final List<EmployeeData> insertedData = this.employeeService.insertEmployeeData(empData, id);
        if (insertedData != null) {
            
            final List<EmployeeData> employeeDataAfterInsertion =
                           this.employeeService.getEmployeeData(employeeId);
            if (employeeDataAfterInsertion != null) {
                return new Gson().toJson(employeeDataAfterInsertion);
            } else {
                throw new EUCCustomException(empConstants.NO_EMPLOYEE_DATA);
            }
            
        } else {
            throw new EUCCustomException(empConstants.EMPLOYEE_INSERT_ERROR_DATA);
        }

    } else {
        throw new EUCCustomException(empConstants.EMPLOYEE_MISSING_HEADER_DATA);
    }

}
```

In the request i have a list empData which contains the data from UI. How can i extract this empData so that i can pass the employeeId in the getEmployeeData method.

Answer (score 0):

EmployeeData should contain 1 employees data, if empData is a List of EmployeeData, it contains multiple employees data.

You should figure out which of the employee you are trying to grab and than use the id.
if you want the first one, you can use it as:

```
  insertedData[0].getEmployeeId()
```

getEmployeeId method should exist in your EmployeeData class.

Answer (score 0):

Is the **empData** not null? I mean, you are sure that **empData** has value inside it, aren't you?

Use foreach to get the value of each **EmployeeData**

```
for (EmployeeData employeeData : empData) {
     ...
     final List employeeDataAfterInsertion =
                           this.employeeService.getEmployeeData(employeeData.getEmployeeId()); // make sure you have set the getter of getEmployeeId() inside EmployeeData class 
     ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks garninth I Have tried this but compiler is asking for a return even though i have a return in my function